# Goodman Gas Pack/AC unit(gpg1424060m41ab) blower fan works all day with heat and AC but will not turn on once its dark to sometime in the morning

Tags: blower, motor

This thread is my exact problem.

[Why does my Goodman a/c blower motor randomly not work?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/141857/why-does-my-goodman-a-c-blower-motor-randomly-not-work?newreg=e39bccf9c91c4cd8827ab0c86d955b74#comment231857_141899)

I have changed out the run capacitor, thr Ignition board, Furnace Vent Air Pressure Switch, transformer, and Condenser Contactor.

The blower motor works perfectly fine during the day. Quits working around 11pm. Using Ecobee Smart thermostat. Tried turning the fan on manually by bypassing the thermostat and the fan doesn't turn on. 24v at the thermostat wires as well.

I've had 2 HVAC companies come out and they can't find anything wrong because it works great during normal hours. Im about to just give up and run space heaters all winter or run the heat to 85 before 11pm and try to get through the night without more heat. It really sucks when it's hot here in the south. No AC or air circulation all night.

Comment: Do you still have the old thermostat, the one before you got the Ecobee? Sounds like a hidden program in the smart thermostat. If you've got the old one, switch it out and see if the problem 's still there.

Comment: Since it is a Ecobee Smart thermostat, someone has a setting on they phone to turn it off at 11PM

Comment: I've tried with the old thermostat and it does the same thing. It's not exactly 11pm every night but its around that time. Sometimes midnight sometimes 10pm. I just know that If I don't set the thermostat to OFF it will kick on the AC when its warm and the unit outside runs but freezes up completely until I turn it off. But the blower fan wont turn on. Same goes for the heat, except the furnace will notice it overheating due the blower not moving the hot air and it shuts off.

Comment: Again, I can bypass the thermostat and get the blower motor to run during the day by touching the corresponding wires together but if I try it at night when I have this issue the blower will never turn on. I've eliminated the thermostat as the problem as well as the wiring because 24v are showing on them.

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram of your unit please?

Comment: **unit outside runs but freezes up completely** - that's low Freon. The *coil* (inside) should freeze with no blower running. w/o the condenser fan running it should get too hot and trip out. - Blower fan works when provided 120v, then the blower works. You've replaced everything except the main CB.... but verify correct Freon levels first... on both sides. If the high side is way too high you have blockage. It's an '80'; how hard you trying to get a few more years out of it?

Comment: Except, "Same goes for the heat, except the furnace will notice it overheating due the blower not moving" - then that's the **main CB / delay timer**. *Not user serviceable*, you need a new board. But dropping *another* ~$200 to see if parts swapping can fix it is up to you.

Comment: It's an all outdoor unit gas pack / Ac unit. The Freon was checked by the last HVAC company and was normal on high and low. The unit is 6 years old. Replaced a year before we bought the house. The control board is the same as the Ignition board. There are no other board modules to change out. Like I said, the unit operates normally from dawn to dusk in both heat and cool modes. Blower motor is the only issue between dusk and dawn

Comment: Okay so it's 9am and 40 degrees and the blower motor will not run even if I try to do fan only. This is the coldest day we have had this season so I haven't seen cold ambient temp factor in. Gas heat turns on for about 2 min and shuts off to prevent overheating from the blower not turning on to distribute the heat.

Comment: ThreePhaseEel I'm not sure where that diagram is.

Comment: So the heat and blower came on twice before it warmed up outside between 930 and 10am. I'm looking at the ecobee stats and it shows between 10:05am and 11:25am the power was lost at the thermostat. Power was not lost in my home, just at that 1 thermostat. Our second floor thermostat worked normally. I'm trying to give as much info as I can. Is it possible it's a bad circuit breaker or something? I have a breaker outside next to the unit as well as one in the garage at the main panel. To me it's like there's a power issue. House was built in 2004. Everything is copper. Not a cheaply built home.

Comment: Seems like I can only get the blower to work when the Ambient outside temperature is above 65ish. I guess everyone else moved on.